# Lambda to delegate resolution

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

I'm currently reading Jon Skeet's C# in depth 2nd edition and the following question came to my mind:

How's the compiler able to choose between `list.Sort(Comparison<T>)` and `list.Sort(MyComparison<T>)` in the following example:

```
// MyComparison has the same signature as Comparison<in T>
public delegate int MyComparison<in T>(T x, T y);

public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    // Sort is like Sort(Comparison<T>) except it takes a MyComparison<T> in parameter
    public int Sort(MyComparison<T> comparison)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sort MyComparison<T>");
        return -1;
    }
}

MyList<Product> list = new MyList<Product>();

list.Sort((product1, product2) => product1.Name.CompareTo(product2.Name));

// Equivalent to
list.Sort(new MyComparison<Product>((product1, product2) => product1.Name.CompareTo(product2.Name)));

// But not equivalent to...
list.Sort(new Comparison<Product>((product1, product2) => product1.Name.CompareTo(product2.Name)));
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If overload resolution comes across an applicable method, it will use that one in preference to *any* methods declared in base classes. So in this case, it's as if `List<T>.Sort` didn't even exist, for the first two invocations.

The third invocation *isn't* applicable, so it will find `List<T>.Sort` instead.

If you declared another overload for `Sort` within `MyList` (but taking `Comparison<T>` instead of `MyComparison<T>`) *then* the method call would be ambiguous.

See my [overload resolution article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) for more details.

PS Hope you're enjoying the book :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. (I do enjoy the book, thank you so much for taking the time to update it).

Answer (score 5):

It chooses that one because it's in the child class and it prefers those.

For example:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int Sort2(MyComparison<T> comparison)
    {
    }
    public int Sort2(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
    }
}
```

In this case, it doesn't understand anymore and:

```
list.Sort2((product1, product2) => product1.Name.CompareTo(product2.Name));
```

and you get an "The call is ambigous" error.

Comment: I accepted Jon's answer as he gave me a link for more detail but considers your answer valid too

Comment: You scored more than him on that one ;)